# How do I test a postconstruct method

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, testng

I have a @PostConstruct method like below:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        if (getPrimaryDirectory() == null) {
            primaryDirectory = new File(localDirectory, DEFAULT_PRIMARY_DIRECTORY);
        }
        FileUtils.forceMkdir(primaryDirectory);

        if (secondaryDirectory() == null) {
            secondaryDirectory = new File(localDirectory, DEFAULT_SECONDARY_DIRECTORY);
        }
        FileUtils.forceMkdir(secondaryDirectory);
    }
```

My sonar analysis complains that some conditions are not covered by tests. For example test for the condition when the primaryDirectory is null.

The values of primaryDirectory are injected from a properties file using @value and expression language.

I tried it using mockito. But I guess, I cannot really mock this because it is @PostConstruct And when I init my mocks, it would already have invoked the init method.
What scenarios should I be testing here and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test it as a pure unit test. Don't connect any annotation processors to this test and just set all values manually and invoke methods explicitly. This way should be proper testing of this function.